# how to pass values from multiple jtextboxes in jframe to another class

Tags: java, swing

I am making java application for my semster project for which I have to implement mvc. I have completed my all views using jpanels. In one panel I have created a form which contains multiple jtextfields. Now i want to pass the values of all those textfields to controller class. what is the best way of doing it?

One way of doing it, that I have figured out is to create getfunction and and save the value of those textfields in array string and return that string from the getfunction. But the probem is that this method wil work for only particular data type. If I have to store the values of some textfields as string and some as integer then the problem will occur.

Comment: I think you need to provide some code. Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: ok wait for a second

Comment: Create a POJO to hold the data you're passing and pass it